# AMD APP SDK (OpenCL) doesn't detect AMD CPU

Tags: opencl, amd-app

I've got an AMD FX-8350 CPU and a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960 GPU on a PC with OpenSUSE Leap x86_64. I want to work with CUDA and OpenCL on it, so I first installed Cuda Toolkit 7.5. That worked fine.

Then, I installed AMD APP SDK 3.0, because I want to work OpenCL on the AMD CPU. That worked fine, it seems. `$AMDAPPSDKROOT` echoes `/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` echoes `/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/`.

After that, I compiled and ran a basic deviceQuery code (basically [this one](http://dhruba.name/2012/08/14/opencl-cookbook-listing-all-devices-and-their-critical-attributes/), but modified to show platform name) with the following command:

```
gcc -L$AMDAPPSDKROOT/lib/x86_64/ -I$AMDAPPSDKROOT/include anotherDeviceQuery.c -lOpenCL
```

The code compiles and executes, but the output only shows the NVIDIA GPU info.

```
Platform NVIDIA CUDA found.
 1. Device: GeForce GTX 960
    1.1 Hardware version: OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
    1.2 Software version: 352.39
    1.3 OpenCL C version: OpenCL C 1.2 
    1.4 Parallel compute units: 8
```

I can't seem to find any solution. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [web page](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/system-requirements-driver-compatibility/), your AMD CPU FX-8350 is not supported by the AMD APP SDK 3.0 (OpenCL 2.0).

All the devices listed there are either GPUs or CPUs with an integrated graphics core (APU). So, I would not expect that your CPU-only will be supported in the near future, because OpenCL is mainly designed to run kernel code on the faster GPU (part).

Comment: I knew x86_64 AMD processors supported OpenCL, but, as you said, apparently AMD APP SDK 3.0 does not support said processors. So, I installed 2.8 version instead, and it worked! Thanks

Comment: Just a comment: Apparently, when executing an OpenCL code on Linux with a supported AMD CPU, the following text will apeear each time:

`Setting of real/effective user Id to 0/0 failed
modprobe: FATAL: Module fglrx not found.
Error! Fail to load fglrx kernel module! Maybe you can switch to root user to load kernel module directly`

Yeah, AMD is wacky.

Comment: @MiguelÁngelGuillénHernández I also tried the `fglrx` driver with my AMD GPU, but failed too. Maybe, your problem is that you actually have a NVIDIA GPU. The APP SDK works fine only on my Windows machine.

Comment: I didn't install the fglrx driver, because I don't have any AMD GPU, and I don't need it to work with an AMD CPU. My OpenCL codes work fine when using the AMD CPU, but the message always appear.